# Losing values by projecting one raster onto another one

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I would like to project one raster to another.

While doing so all the values get lost.

This is the original raster `rb` I would like to project:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 900, 900, 810000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +units=km +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 2500  (min, max)
```

So I create a `dest_raster`:

```
 dest_raster_crs<- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +zone=34 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  dest_raster<-raster(ncols=900,nrows=900,crs= dest_raster_crs)
  extent(dest_raster) <- extent(-523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645)
```

`dest_raster` looks like this:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 900, 900, 810000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Now if i do the projection with :

```
  new_raster<-projectRaster(rb, dest_raster,res=c(1,1), dest_raster_crs,over=T)
```

I get this error:

```
Warning message:
In rgdal::rawTransform(projto_int, projfrom, nrow(xy), xy[, 1],  :
  29700 projected point(s) not finite
```

And if i look at `new_raster` all the values are `NA`

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 900, 900, 810000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : NA, NA  (min, max)
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that i used wrong system while doing the extension

Correct way would be:

```
  extent(dest_raster) <- extent(3.5889,14.6209, 47.0705, 54.7405)
```